# Redirect back to list view with page number

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a function to withdrow some recored
I can click the withdrow from the list page and the details..So,I want to check first what is the current path inorder to getback to it after showing message.

I have used the next method to handle that it is working fine for the details page but for the list page it is not working if the url contain ex.`?page=2` it will show `Page not found 404`

template

```html
<a href="{% url 'records:withdrow-record' pk=record.id %}?next={{ request.path }}">withdrow record </a>
```

view.py

```py
def withdrowRecord(request, pk):
if condition:
      do stuff...
else:
      messages.error(request, _('cannot withdrow a recored without permission'))
      url_name = resolve(request.GET.get("next")).url_name
      if url_name == 'record-details':
          return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('records:record-details', args=(pk,)))
      elif url_name == 'record-list':
          return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get("next"))
```

I have tried to change request.path in the template to `?next={{ request.get_full_path }}` and it is not working same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [**`|urlencode`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) the path, since this can contain characters like `?` and `&` that needs to be escaped as well:

```
<a href="{% url 'records:withdrow-record' pk=record.id %}?next={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}">
```

If the path itself contains characters like `?`, `&`, `*`, etc. these need to be [*percent-encoded* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), since otherwise it will make the path ambiguous: is the `&` a separator for the other querystring parameter, or is it part of the content of `next=`. Therefore in a querystring, the key and value need to be percent-encoded to ensure non-ambiguity.

The view can also not resolve the `next` parameter if it contains itself querystrings. You need to strip these from the path:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

# …

url_path = request.GET.get('next').path
url_name = resolve(url_path).url_name
```

The name of the view, `withdrow-record` suggests that you modify entities. The [HTTP specifications](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) however state that GET request should be *safe*. This thus means that changes to the entities are not allowed. This is also unsafe since a search engine could accidentally trigger such action, and furthermore Django will not check a CSRF token to see if the request is not the result of [*cross-site request forgery* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: thanks for your response,, but even after I added the |urlencode , it is not working tha issue is it wo'nt redirect to the path with the page parm

Comment: @GHS: sorry should be `get_full_path`. I think in order to debug this, it is important to check what `request.GET` contains. Furthermore you should also wrap `resolve` in `try`-`except` since a person can "*forge*" a URL.

Comment: yeh I have tried it with the full path , same error page not found :(

Comment: @GHS: exactlly *what* page is not found, the one in the `href`, or the one to which the view redirects later?

Comment: @GHS: The name of the view is furthermore `withdrow-record`, if that makes changes to entities, you can not do that per GET request, since that violates the HTTP standard (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). A GET request is supposed to have no *side-effects*.

Comment: the one in the next value in href ,, it is showing ```Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/recoreds/withdrow-record/127?next=/ recoreds/external/archived/%3Fpage%3D2```.. ```The current path, recoreds/external/archived/?page=2, didn't match any of these.```

Comment: @GHS: ah, but that is because `resolve` never takes the querystring into account, so you need to strip that from the string before you pass it to the `resolve` function.